# From which Greek dialect did Hebrew borrow *awēr* "air"?

Tags: greek, loanwords, hebrew, borrowing

The Hebrew for "air" is אוויר *avir*, earlier *awīr* or *awēr*. This is obviously a borrowing of the Greek word that appears in Attic as ἀήρ, and would be ἀϝήρ in other dialects. The Hebrew word must have been borrowed from a Greek dialect that retained intervocalic digamma, but which dialect?

Klein's etymological dictionary of Hebrew simply says "from Greek" without specifying further. There were numerous dialects in which intervocalic digamma survived. Do we know, or can we plausibly guess, which dialect was the source of this loanword?

Comment: Very interesting; I would have immediately thought Koine (post-Alexander) but that wouldn't have a digamma either.

Comment: +1 Indeed, apparently in the Hebrew Bible the "air" is referred to as "skies/heaven" (*shamayim*.)

Answer (score 5):

The Greek ἀήρ seems to have entered (post-Biblical) Hebrew via Aramaic ʼwwyr. Syriac Aramaic also has the more Greek-looking form ʼʼr. The replacement of an intervocalic glottal stop by a semi-vowel (here: ʼāʼer > ʼāwer) is typical of Aramaic, and other Semitic languages.

Comment: The replacement of an internal glottal stop with a semi-vowel seems reasonable enough, but the choice of [w] in this environment seems counter-intuitive.  I should have expected something like [ʔajer] instead.  Are other examples of this?

Comment: @varro. As it happens, Mandaic Aramaic has this word as ʼyʼr, for /āyar/.

Comment: Interesting -- so the *w* is an accidental similarity... Like varro, I'm curious about the odd change VʔV > VwV. Is it regular in Aramaic?

Comment: @TKR. E.g. Syriac active participle pāʾeḵ¸but imperative poḵ.